# Postfix logging incomplete after changing myhostname

Tags: postfix, logging, syslog

My postfix installation does not log most of the messages after changing `myhostname`. The `myhostname` is now different from the FQDN (and hostname) of the machine where it used to be the same. After changing this (for other reasons) the logging to syslog stopped working for the delivery and queing part. Only some warnings are logged.

When i set the `maillog_file` parameter all the logging appears there as expected and works as before the name change. There is however 1 thing i notice: in the log-line i see the `myhostname` in stead of the machine hostname.

I am using rsyslogd on debian with an (for mail) unmodified configuration.

What am i missing? I would like it back to use full syslog logging for obvious reasons....

config and versions:

```
# rsyslogd -v
rsyslogd  8.2102.0 (aka 2021.02) compiled with:
        PLATFORM:                               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

# cat /var/log/postfix-mail.log |grep -i started|head -n 1
Jun 29 15:44:36 gateway postfix/master[2639374]: daemon started -- version 3.5.6, configuration /etc/postfix

# uname -a
Linux ***** 5.10.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.84-1 (2021-12-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye

# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
lmtp_tls_fingerprint_digest = sha256
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maillog_file = /var/log/postfix-mail.log
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = gateway.my.domain
mynetworks = local-lan-ips/24 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_fingerprint_digest = sha256
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301 inet:127.0.0.1:11332
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/FQDN/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_fingerprint_digest = sha256
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/FQDN/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtputf8_enable = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

# postconf -M
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog    unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Comment: Logging shouldn't depend on myhostname and/or system hostname. But maybe it is not logged because it is not being performed? Is delivery happening at all?

Comment: Everything is working fine wether it is logging or not: when i set the `maillog_file` the logging appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the cause of my problem....

After reading 100's of pages i found out that logging is done by systemd-journald. systemd-journald forwards the logs to (r)syslog. My "problem" was the setting `MaxLevelSyslog` which was set at `notice`. My missing log messages from postfix were of level info. So the whole problem had nothing to do with syslog nor postfix. Hope this helps someone in the future.